# Childs override parent android layout weight size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I want to succeed the following layout

```
*<LinearLayout> 
  *<ListView with standard height = 50% of screen>
  *<TableLayout with standard height = 20% of screen>
  *<Fragment with standard height = 30% of screen> 
*</LinearLayout>
```

The problem here is that the Listview will have 0-infinite items some times. 
When there is no item on the list, Tablelayout and fragment goes up to the screen.

How can i tell to Listview to not calculate size based on listitem views?

I have already tried the following, having the Android studio preview present a correct ui, but when running on device the FrameLayout has height = 0 because the list is empty.

```
*<LinearLayout>
*  <FrameLayout and LinearLayout with weight>
*    <ListView>
*  </FrameLayout and /LinearLayout> 

*  <TableLayout with standard with weight>
*<Fragment with standard with weight>
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: can you post your xml file, please?

Comment: you can set custom emptyview on listview to occupy space when list is empty

Comment: I think there is no more information in xml file than i have already applied, right?
The question here is,

"Why layout child components affect parents layout height which is based on weight"

"In what layout can i add the ListView (if the framelayout is the problem) in order to keep the layout height independent from Listview height.

Comment: Thanks Imran but this could work but i have to calculate based on the listview height(depends on different devices) the number of empty item views to add in order my list have the appropriate height. 

This is a pain that i don't want to have.

Answer (score 0):

the only solution I can think of is like that

```
*<LinearLayout>
  *<ListView with standard height = 50% of screen>
  *<View with standard height = 50% of screen visibily=gone>
  *<TableLayout with standard height = 20% of screen>
  *<Fragment with standard height = 30% of screen> 
*</LinearLayout>
```

then when you find out that the ListView has 0 items change the visibility of the view.